# Google Apps Script - UiApp ServerHandler Callback function - values are undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write an UI for a Google Spreadsheet that reads out all labels of my Gmail account, puts these in a listbox. I should be then able to select one item of that list and keep working with it.

When I am trying to do that, I always get an undefined value for `e.parameter.mylist` - any ideas... I feel like I am missing a big part of the concept...

```js
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'by label', functionName: 'fShowUI'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Gmail export', menuItems);
}

function fShowUI() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Google Mail - Label export');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();  
  var mylist = myapp.createListBox().setId('mylist');
  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Select label').setId('mybutton');

  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    mylist.addItem(labels[i].getName())
  } 

  callbackHandler = myapp.createServerHandler("fButtonConfirm");
  callbackHandler.addCallbackElement(mypanel);
  mybutton.addClickHandler(callbackHandler);

  mypanel.add(mylist);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);

  /* Return myapp to display the UiInstance object and all elements associated with it. */
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  spreadsheet.show(myapp);
}

function fButtonConfirm(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.toast(e.parameter.mylist);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't mind, but I'm going to try giving [fishing lessons](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/maimonides326751.html)...

It helps to use logging when debugging code like this. I like using Peter Hermann's [BetterLog library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog), which will capture all logs into a spreadsheet, so is more persistent than a `toast()` or `alert()`. As an added benefit as you keep building your app, it will allow you to log events on both server and client side to track interactions.

Add it as a resource / library, then pop this line at the top of your (spreadsheet-bound) script, and you're ready to go:

```js
Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet();
```

Let's log the parameter being received by the handler:

```js
function fButtonConfirm(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,2));  // readable JSON structure
  ...
```

Here's what we get in the "Log" sheet:

```js
2014-11-28 20:52:58:249 -0500 000105 INFO {
  "parameter": {
    "clientY": "38",
    "clientX": "39",
    "source": "mybutton",
    "button": "1",
    "alt": "false",
    "eventType": "click",
    "screenY": "333",
    "ctrl": "false",
    "screenX": "472",
    "y": "12",
    "shift": "false",
    "meta": "false",
    "x": "35"
  }
}
```

Hmm. No `mylist` in there.

Check the documentation for [Class ServerHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler), and we find:

> When a ServerHandler is called, any widgets added here, as well as any current child widgets of those widgets, are considered as callback elements. The value of each of these widgets is added to the information sent to the script processing the event, as long as the following two conditions are met:
>
> - The callback element has a "setName" method.
> - A name has been set.

And we see `mylist` has an ID, but no Name. Fix that...

```js
var mylist = myapp.createListBox().setId('mylist').setName('mylist');
```

And on the next run our log shows:

```js
2014-11-28 21:06:11:615 -0500 000086 INFO {
  "parameter": {
    "clientY": "31",
    "clientX": "24",
    "eventType": "click",
    "mylist": "Archive - Other",   <<<<<<< Success!
    "ctrl": "false",
    "meta": "false",
    "source": "mybutton",
    "button": "1",
    "alt": "false",
    "screenY": "326",
    "screenX": "457",
    "shift": "false",
    "y": "5",
    "x": "20"
  }
}
```

Now we can comment out or otherwise disable that log, and move on to the next <s>fish</s> problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I think this should get me plenty fish... especially with such a nice expanded logger.